# ValueError: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 4 for 'adjust_hue/Slice' (op: 'Slice') with input shapes: [384,12,12,3], [3], [3]

Tags: python, tensorflow

While working on a TensorFlow project, I've encountered a problem and I don't know how to solve it. I have

[image]

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 4 for 'adjust_hue/Slice' (op: 'Slice') with input shapes: [384,12,12,3], [3], [3].

Comment: could you post part of the code which is throwing this error message?

Comment: Thank you for your replying, i will post the code tomorrow when i go to my lab, ok?

Comment: Hi, here is part of the code, plz check it.                                                                    input_image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[config.BATCH_SIZE, image_size, image_size, 3], name='input_image')
    label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[config.BATCH_SIZE], name='label')
    bbox_target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[config.BATCH_SIZE, 4], name='bbox_target')
    landmark_target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[config.BATCH_SIZE,10],name='landmark_target')

Answer (score 3):

according to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8926

some `tf.image` functions only accept a single image as an input.

but some image ops (e.g. `tf.image.random_brightness()`, `tf.image.random_contrast()`) allow batches.

the solution is using lambda to work on batch:

```
    hue = lambda x: tf.image.random_hue(x, 0.5)
    inputs = tf.map_fn(hue, inputs)
```

Comment: Thank you, I came across the same issue and your post helped me. This works for me:
`def image_color_distort(inputs):
    inputs = tf.image.random_contrast(inputs, lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
    inputs = tf.image.random_brightness(inputs, max_delta=0.2)
    hue = lambda x: tf.image.random_hue(x, max_delta= 0.2)
    inputs = tf.map_fn(hue, inputs)
    saturation = lambda x: tf.image.random_saturation(x, lower = 0.5, upper= 1.5)
    inputs = tf.map_fn(saturation, inputs)
    return inputs`

Answer (score 0):

Just delete/comment  tf.image.random_hue and image.random_saturation in function image_color_distort at train.py like the code bellow:

```
def image_color_distort(inputs):
    inputs = tf.image.random_contrast(inputs, lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
    inputs = tf.image.random_brightness(inputs, max_delta=0.2)
    # inputs = tf.image.random_hue(inputs,max_delta= 0.2)
    # inputs = tf.image.random_saturation(inputs,lower = 0.5, upper= 1.5)

    return inputs
```